# Bypassing login and passing env variables as url param in Jupyterhub kubernetes google cloud deployment

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm, jupyterhub

Let me tell you about my application.

WHAT I WANT TO DO :

- My frontend make a get request to some URL with some url params like http://x.x.x.x/?notebook-name=normalisation_script.ipynb&open-type=open_extisting_notebook&project-id=1111&user=user_one&token=345678654567890989765435hbgt654567yt
- My pod which get the above request and tell kubernetes to start the user pod should set the URL params as an environment variables for in docker container.
- Docker entry-point script uses those env variables to select which task to run.

I have to open my notebook in iframe so it should just bypass all the steps like login and start the server.

I am using docker-stack/datascience-notebook image after updating its entry-point.

WHAT I HAVE DONE TILL NOW :

- By following zero-to-jupyterhub-with-kubernetes documentation i was able to host jupyterhub server on google cloud platform (zero-to-jupyterhub-with-kubernetes documentation use jupyterhub/jupyterhub helm chart to deploy the application on kubernetes).
- I am bypassing login and start of the server using TmpAuthentication.
  For now, I am defining my env variables in extraEnv for helm-chart config.yaml file.

My helm chart config file looks like this.

```
hub:
    cookieSecret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    extraConfig: |
        import tmpauthenticator
        c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = tmpauthenticator.TmpAuthenticator
        c.Authenticator.auto_login = True
proxy:
    secretToken: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
cull:
    timeout: 60
    every: 30
singleuser:
  storage:
    type: none
  image:
    name: kushalgupta/datascience-notebook
    tag: '0.35'
  extraEnv:
    POLLY_FUNC: "open_new_notebook"
    POLLY_NOTEBOOK_NAME: "my-notebook-custom-on-gcloud"
    POLLY_PROJECT_ID: 1172
    POLLY_TYPE: "http://testpolly.elucidata.io"
```

NEED HELP IN :

- Open notebook in browser just by hitting the URL like this http://x.x.x.x/?notebook-name=normalisation_script.ipynb&open-type=open_extisting_notebook&project-id=1111&user=user_one&token=345678654567890989765435hbgt654567yt
- Set those URL params as env variables in a docker container.

I am new to the backend technologies and don't know how to this.
Can anyone knows or have some idea how can I achieve this.
Thanks.